# Does weak convergence on an Hilbert space imply regular convergence?

Tags: hilbert-spaces, weak-convergence

I have to prove that if the series $$\sum x_n$$ converges weakly then it converges (normally)

my solution goes as follows:

$\langle \sum x_n | y\rangle \rightarrow \langle x|y\rangle $, for all $y\in H$ (Hilbert space).

Then, $\sum \langle x_n| \rightarrow \langle x| \iff \langle \sum x_n|\rightarrow \langle x| \iff \sum x_n \rightarrow x$

the thing is the exercises says that $x_n$ are orthonormal, which I didn't use.

Comment: $y_n\to x$ in $H$ means $\|y_n-x\|_H\to 0$

Comment: Use `\langle,\rangle` to get $\langle x\rangle$

Comment: $x_n=e_n-e_{n-1}$ gives a counter-example where $(e_n)$ is an orthonormal basis. See where your proof fails in this case.